# CSS background won't scroll with content

Tags: html, css, background

My CSS is:

```
body {
     background-color: {color:background};
     background-image: url({image:background});
     background-attachment: scroll;
     background-size: auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center
     min-height: 500px;
     margin: 0;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

The background just stays at the top and doesn't move even after messing with the different settings to a potential fix the background then moves up as you scroll down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your html

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wPeaAs0i its for a tumblr blog im trying to help edit.